# How do I get capture.output functionality while capturing ANSI color codes from crayon?

Tags: r

What ways are there to capture output *à la* `capture.output` but which will retain the ANSI color encoding which comes out of `crayon`?

```r
> crayon::green("green")
[1] "\033[32mgreen\033[39m"
> capture.output(crayon::green("green"))
[1] "[1] \"green\""
```

Edit:  Another example

```r
> green <- function() {
+   print(crayon::green("green"))
+   cat(crayon::green("green"))
+   
+   invisible()
+ }
> green()
[1] "\033[32mgreen\033[39m"
green
> capture.output(green())
[1] "[1] \"green\"" "green"        
>
```

Comment: So, you want to capture first output string i.e `"\033[32mgreen\033[39m"` right?

Comment: @sm925 correct.

Comment: You can save first line of your code to a variable and then do `capture.output` on it. Like this: `x <- crayon::green("green")
capture.output(x)` Does that work for you?/

Comment: @sm925 That works for this case, but in the broader sense, I need `capture.output` to catch messages that are output while a function is running, not just the single resulting object.

Comment: Could you please add an example of such function to your question?

Comment: @sm925 sure thing.  I think really I am trying to get to the underlying cause that is stripping the ANSi codes.  I think it is happening inside of `sink` (called by `capture.output`), but I don't know why nor how to get around it.

Comment: @TylerSmith did you ever resolve this? I would be interested in being able to capture ANSI-enhanced text from `crayon::` messages.

Comment: @r2evans I did not.  But I decided to look at it again with fresh eyes and posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I believe the issue arises with the `crayon::has_color()` function which is called when any of the crayon functions are run.  This function calls https://github.com/r-lib/crayon/blob/4a44bb262615ab5c4e30cb80437d9f2e24ccb006/R/aab-num-ansi-colors.R#L36-L267

Looking at what the function does: when called within `capture.output` `crayon:::num_ansi_colors()` will typically return `1L` because it detects the presence of the sink.  This can be worked around by setting  `options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)`.

```r
green <- function() {
  print(crayon::green("green"))
  cat(crayon::green("green"))
  invisible()
}
capture.output(green())
#> [1] "[1] \"green\"" "green"
withr::with_options(list(crayon.enabled = TRUE), capture.output(green()))
#> [1] "[1] \"\\033[32mgreen\\033[39m\"" "\033[32mgreen\033[39m"
```